# How can I disable multiple buttons?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have 2 buttons on my view and i want to disable the first button when i click on an other button and disable the second when I click again on the button.

I have tried with this code

```
if (button1.enable = NO) {
    button2.enable = NO;
}
```

So I have in a NavigationBar a "+" button and 5 disable buttons in my view.
When I push the "+" button I want to enable the first button and when I push again that enable the second…
Thanks

Comment: How does that code disable any buttons?

Comment: Can you provide more info? It is difficult to understand what you're trying to ask here...

Answer (score 3):

```
if (button1.enabled == YES)
{
     button1.enabled = NO;
     button2.enabled = YES;
}
else (button2.enabled == YES)
{
     button2.enabled = NO;
     button1.enabled = YES;
}
```

Is that what your looking for? It would be an IBAction for the other button.

Answer (score 0):

You're saying

```
if (button1.enabled = NO) {
```

when you probably mean

```
if (button1.enabled == NO) {
```

`=` is the assignment operator, and `==` is the boolean equality operator. What you're doing at the moment is assigning YES to button1.enable, which obviously enables button1. Then, because button.enable is true, control enters the if's clause and enables button2.

EDIT: To answer your new question ("When I push the "+" button I want to enable the first button and when I push again that enable the second..."), let's say that you initialise the button states somewhere. In your @interface add an instance variable

```
NSArray *buttons;
```

so your interface declaration looks something like

```
@interface YourViewController: UIViewController {
  IBOutlet UIButton *button1;
  IBOutlet UIButton *button2;
  IBOutlet UIButton *button3;
  IBOutlet UIButton *button4;
  IBOutlet UIButton *button5;
  NSArray *buttons;
}
```

and then initialise `buttons` like so:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  buttons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, nil];
  [buttons retain];
  for (UIButton *each in buttons) {
    each.enabled = NO;
  }

-(void)viewDidUnload {
  [buttons release];
  [super viewDidUnload];
}
```

Let's say you hook up the + button's Touch Up Inside event handler to `plusPressed:`. Then you'd have

```
-(IBAction)plusPressed: (id) button {
  for (UIButton *each in buttons) {
    if (!each.enabled) {
      each.enabled = YES;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Each time `plusPressed:` is called, the next button in the array will be enabled. (I'm writing the above away from a compiler; there may be syntax errors.)

You could also make `buttons` a property. I didn't, because other classes have no business accessing `buttons`.

Comment: thank you but when I add the code i have a error 
"Expected expression before 'UIButton' for the line 
"foreach (UIButton *each in Buttons)

thanks again

Comment: Try again? I had a ; where I should have written a {

Comment: and i have a 1 warning :
implicit declaration of function 'foreach'

Comment: Like I said: I'm away from a compiler. Turns out that a foreach loop uses "for", not "foreach". Please try again.

Comment: no..., now when i click on the "+" the app crash... and i don't have any warning or error...

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint on the for and seeing what the various bits look like? Are button1..button5 actually hooked up to the bits in the nibfile?

Comment: yes, i have tried and I have a syntax error :/ and yes my buttons are connected :/

Comment: I'm missing something. You say your application crashes, which indicates that it compiles, which means the syntax is fine... but you have a syntax error? What is the error? Are button1..button5 initialised (non-nil) in viewDidLoad?

Comment: Oops sry, I actually don't speak English i normally speak French... 
And for the Buttons in my viewDidLoad I have this Button1.enabled = NO;
 Button2.enabled = NO;
 Button3.enabled = NO;
 Button4.enabled = NO;
 Button5.enabled = NO;
Thanks

Comment: the console say that "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
reason: '-[NSCFString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b46610'"

Comment: I have try in a new project with only your code and it's doesn't work... The five buttons are not enabled but when i click nothing happens
I don't have any warning or error.
Thanks for your help

Comment: So I assume that the viewDidLoad part above works correctly, right? When you put a breakpoint in plusPressed and click the + control does actually reach that breakpoint? What type is each in the for loop? (You mention "Button1.enabled = NO" - Button1 is not the same as button1.)

Comment: hi, when I put a breakpoint in plusPressed and press the + my app crash and Xcode show this line "for (UIButton *each in Buttons) {"
and I have renamed buttons,button1,2,3,4,5 for Buttons,Button1,2,3,4,5.
Thanks

Comment: The algorithm's sound. The problem's that buttons needs to be retained.

Answer (score 0):

`button1.enable = YES` should be `button1.enable == YES`

a better readable form: `[button1 isEnabled]`